# Best Hive SQL query for this

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, memory-optimized-tables

i have 2 table something like this. i'm running a hive query and windows function seems pretty limited in hive.

Table dept

```
id | name |
1 | a |
2 | b |
3 | c |
4 | d |
```

Table time (build with heavy load query so it's make a very slow process if i need to join to another newly created table time.)

```
id | date | first | last |
1 | 1992-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
2 | 1993-02-02 | 1 | 2 |
2 | 1993-03-03 | 2 | 1 |
3 | 1993-01-01 | 1 | 3 |
3 | 1994-01-01 | 2 | 2 |
3 | 1995-01-01 | 3 | 1 |
```

i need to retrieve something like this :

```
SELECT d.id,d.name,
t.date AS firstdate,
td.date AS lastdate
FROM dbo.dept d LEFT JOIN dbo.time t ON d.id=t.id AND t.first=1
LEFT JOIN time td ON d.id=td.id AND td.last=1
```

How the most optimized answer ?

Comment: Put constant comparison (ie, `t.first=1`) in the `where` clause, not the `join` clause.  Other than that, this looks pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Donnie I'm new at these hive table, this time table is built by a complicated `SELECT` query, what i trying to do is to make time table only called once, is it possible ?

@TimBiegeleisen i need a single query to done this. and this table are built by heavy works, actually best approach is using temp table maybe but i don't know how is the best for using it in hive.

Comment: @Donnie - This will not be logically equivalent to the original query

Comment: I assume there is no more than one row where `first`/`last` = 1 per dept?

Comment: yep, they're generated by row number, i just simplify it as temp table in question.

Comment: i edit the question to make it more viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` operation that will be done in a single map-reduce job

```
select      id
           ,max(name)   as name
           ,max(case when first = 1 then `date` end) as firstdate
           ,max(case when last  = 1 then `date` end) as lastdate

from       (select      id
                       ,null as name 
                       ,`date`         
                       ,first         
                       ,last 

            from        time

            where       first = 1
                    or  last  = 1

            union all  

            select      id 
                       ,name         
                       ,null as `date` 
                       ,null as first 
                       ,null as last  

            from        dept
            ) t

group by    id 
;
```

---

```
+----+------+------------+------------+
| id | name | firstdate  |  lastdate  |
+----+------+------------+------------+
|  1 | a    | 1992-01-01 | 1992-01-01 |
|  2 | b    | 1993-02-02 | 1993-03-03 |
|  3 | c    | 1993-01-01 | 1995-01-01 |
|  4 | d    | (null)     | (null)     |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: See updated answer (adjusted to the new data sample)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, that save it !

Comment: You're welcome. P.s. see updated answer for added `WHERE` clause that might improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      d.id
       ,max(d.name)   as name
       ,max(case when t.first = 1 then t.date end) as 'firstdate'
       ,max(case when t.last  = 1 then t.date end) as 'lastdate'

from      dept d  left join  
      time t on d.id = t.id
where     t.first = 1  or  t.last  = 1
group by  d.id
```

Comment: I actually already use this kind of query, getting the gist of query logic from first answer, `UNION ALL` faster than normal `JOIN` btw. But thanks nonetheless !